# Display link to full change form for object in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Because nested inlines are not yet supported, I am wondering how to display a link to the related object as an alternative. I came across a question the other day with a link to an app, but I can't seem to find it again.

Here is what I am looking at doing:
I have a manager model that contains name, address etc.

I have a property model that has inlines and is related to the manager model.

I am wanting the manager model to be able to display a link in the change form for each of the properties that are related to it.

Is this something that can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just overwrite your change view.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view

Copy the template from the real admin template directory and place it anywhere you like (since you can point at it with `change_form_template`, and add in some extra stuff to display.

I do this pretty commonly.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'myapp/new_change_form.html'

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        properties = Manager.objects.get(id=object_id).property_set.all()
        extra_context = { 'properties':properties }
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

Find a place in the admin template to add some of your own HTML.

```
<ul>
{% for property in properties %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url admin:myapp_manager_change property.id %}">Edit {{ property }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping I could find that app yet to see if it would work. But this method works perfectly as well.

Comment: Yeah, nested inlines sounds pretty neat. :)