# Django - Adding related books to the author

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship

Lets take the standard example

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  #... Many other fields ...
```

On the admin interface from the `Author` change page, I'd like to be able to add/edit his `Books`.

There you are going to tell me please RTFM and use a [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).
But wait, as you can see there are "Many other fields" in `Books` and it will not be easily editable.

What I imagined is to be able to simply display the book titles in the `Author` change page, and supply links to add or edit his books. How can I do that ?

Comment: Hey. Think this should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035709/display-link-to-full-change-form-for-object-in-django-admin

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot, (and [this one too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051535/django-accessing-set-from-admin-change-page)). If you want to make a little answer, I'll validate it with pleasure, even if it's just 1 or 2 links :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `change_view` and/or edit the change_form template.

There's a section in the docs you can consult on this topic: [Overriding vs. replacing an admin template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template)

Some more specific information can be found here: [Display link to full change form for object in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035709/display-link-to-full-change-form-for-object-in-django-admin)