# Django - Accessing _set from Admin change page

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

Lets take the standard example

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
  #... Many other fields ...
```

From the admin change template of `Author` trying to access to the related books

```
<ul>
  {% for book in original.book_set.all %}
    <li>
      <a href="{% url admin:myapp_manager_change book.id %}">Edit {{ book }}</a>
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I get

> Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'myapp_manager_change' with arguments '(1L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Why ?
And how can I access this `book_set` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the docs on [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

You have to replace "myapp" with your actual app:

```
admin:{{ app_label }}_{{ model_name }}_change object_id
```

So if your app is named library and your model's name is book the link would be:

```
<a href="{% url admin:library_book_change book.id %}">Edit {{ book }}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it's so obvious, I was trying to use the `URL reversing system` without knowing.

Answer (score 1):

book_set actually works well in your example because the exception is raised from inside the 
`for` loop. It seems the problem is with the view name.

Try this:

```
{% url admin:myapp_book_change book.id %}
```

Comment: Thank you I changed `myapp` to _my_actual_app_ and `manager` to _my_actual_model_ :)